# Erro de conexão com SQL Server 2012 com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, linux

Estou tentando conectar ao SQL Server 2012 utilizando Python 3.7 e Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS da seguinte forma:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'tcp:192.168.0.7, 1433'
database = 'teste'
username = 'teste'
password = 'teste'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

Ao tentar a conexão recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+
> password) pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001]
> [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider:
> [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported
> protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Eu li um [tópico no git](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1056) sobre e até cheguei a testar um downgrade no openssl mas ainda sim não consegui ainda fazer funcionar.

Tenho 2 versões do SQL
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Notei agora que:
Na versão 11.0.2100.60 e tenho o erro que descrevi no começo.
Na versão 11.0.6020.0, notei agora que recebo um erro diferente:

> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+'
> ;PWD=' + password+';Encrypt' + encrypt) pyodbc.OperationalError:
> ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Para instalar o ODBC no Ubuntu 20.04, você seguiu os passos de "Instalar o Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server (Linux)"?  -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

Comment: Verifique também se na instância SQL Server 2012 foi instalado o suporte para o TLS 1.2. "Suporte a TLS 1.2 para o Microsoft SQL Server" -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Para instalar o ODBC Driver for SQL Server (Linux) foi exatamente esse passo a passo que segui, vou verificar o segundo link.

Comment: @JoséDiz, pelo que entendi no site da microsoft a minha versão do SQL não suporta a conexão correto? Adicionei 2 instancias que tenho em versões diferentes, na versão mais nova notei que o erro é diferente.

Comment: Tem certeza que a variável `server` está correta? Não deveria ser apenas `server = '192.168.0.7'`?

Comment: @PauloMarques Sim, [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) consultei na doc

Comment: @wilian, baseado na documentação `# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port` não tem espaço depois da vírgula. Não custa tentar...

Comment: @PauloMarques teste, mesmo erro, tentei assim: server = 'myserver,port', server = 'tcp:myserver,port' server = 'tcp:myserver' na versão nova do sql sempre o erro ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: @wilian, baseado na primeira mensagem, o erro é de SSL, não tem problema com a conexão, mas com a negociação... Veja [este](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/610) post

Comment: pelo que li no git, o que acorre é que é está sendo realizado uma tentativa de conexao com tsl 1.2 e a versão do sql server não atualizada permite apenas 1.0, seria interessante atualizar o bd ou dar downgrade no driver

Comment: @willian As imagens que você acrescentou na descrição não se referem à versão do SQL Server mas sim dos componentes do Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

É necessário verificar se a instância com SQL Server 2012 trata o protocolo TLS v1.2. O primeiro passo é descobrir qual é o nível de atualização do software SQL Server. Uma forma simples é

```
PRINT @@version
```

Para que o protocolo TLS v1.2 seja reconhecido é necessário avaliar qual o service pack instalado e qual o nível de atualização. Se for `2012 SP2` deve-se aplicar o patch `2012 SP2 CU10` que fará com que o build# fique 11.0.5644.2. Mas se for `2012 SP3` então deve-se aplicar o patch `2012 SP3 CU1` que fará com que o build# fique 11.0.6518.0. Mas o melhor mesmo é aplicar o patch `2012 SP4` e a seguir o `2012 SP4 GDR`, que terá todas as atualizações disponíveis para o SQL Server 2012.

Caso não seja possível atualizar o software SQL Server 2012, então você pode configurar para que o OpenSSL aceite TLS v1.1 ou v1.0.

---

Sugestão de leitura:

- [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3135244/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)
- [Latest updates for Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)
- [Atualização SQL Server](https://portosql.wordpress.com/sql-server/atualizacao/)

Comment: Questão do problema de versão TLS resolvido, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Will, você pode testar o seguinte:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/database')
```

ou

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database')
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html